# Gallery strip like in telegram

Tags: android

I would like to make image sharing easier by implementing what Telegram does to send a picture:

[image]

That is, a gallery strip with the latest pictures.

But until now I've only worked with external intents to launch the native gallery.

How can I implement this? Do I have to manually search the phone for pictures? I assume I require strong permissions for this?

Comment: strong permissions = read_external_storage